# Is $\ln\{E[f(x)]\}$ equal to $E\{\ln[f(x)]\}$?

Tags: expected-value, logarithm

Is the logarithm of an expectation the same as the expectation of the logarithm?

Comment: A special case of this statement, if true, would be "the arithmetic mean of positive numbers always equals their geometric mean."  That contradicts a very well known inequality: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means.

Answer (score 6):

No, it's not true. For a counter-example, we have [Jensen's inequality](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Jensen%27s_inequality), which implies $f(E[X])\geq E[f(X)]$, for [concave](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Concave_function) functions, in which $\log x $ is also concave as in your case.

Or, for a concrete example, take $X\in\{1,2\}$ with equal probability. $\log(E[X])=\log(3/2)$ while $E[\log(X)]=\frac{1}{2}\log 2$, which are not equal.

Comment: +1, note that the inequality is strict when $f(x)$ is strictly concave (unless $X$ is degenerate).

Comment: @knrumsey The idea's correct, but it's not quite that simple.  Consider the case where $X$ is a Uniform variable, for instance and $f$ is linear on $[0,1]$ but strictly concave outside that range.

Comment: @whuber, I don't see that as a counterexample to my statement. The function that you posit is not *strictly* concave. I agree it's not the "whole picture" however. Consider the function $f(x) = x^2 I(x > 0)$. This function is not strictly concave, but the inequality will still be strict for a Uniform variable.

Comment: @knrumsey That's part of my point: sometimes the inequality will be strict, sometimes not, even when $f$ is strictly concave in the sense of being strictly concave *somewhere.*  It sounds like you intended it to be strictly concave *everywhere,* which is fine now that your meaning is clear.

Answer (score 2):

No by Jensen's inequality we have $\log(\mathbb{E}[X])\geq \mathbb{E}[\log(X)] $ as $\log(\cdot)$ is a concave function.